# Implement a bottle spin

Tags: python

I want to create a spin the bottle game because I'm bored and what to test my coding skills (they're not that great ngl).  I got this far and wanted to add a feature where the program asks how many people are playing and then it will change the output to that. For example, it asks how many players and if you respond with '8', it will then ask for 8 names and pick from those said names.

I have tried doing:

```
players = input('How many people are playing?')

if player == '2':
 name1 = input(Who is player 1?')
 name2 = input('Who is player 2?')

elif player == '3'
 name1 = input(Who is player 1?')
 name2 = input('Who is player 2?')
 name3 = input ('Who is player 3?')
```

and so forth

```
import random
import time
print ('Hello and welcome to spin the bottle generator')
name1 = input('Who is player 1?')
name2 = input ('Who is player 2?')
name3 = input('Who is player 3?')
name4 = input ('Who is player 4?')


names = [name1, name2, name3, name4]
print (names)
print ('Spinning')
time.sleep(1)
print (random.choice(names))
```

I submitted this code and it asked for the number of players and when I inputted '4' as a test it didnt go any further :/

Comment: Sorry if there are mistakes i am new to programming, just need some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you are tempted to use an undetermined number of variables like `name1`, `name2`, it's a big clue that you should not be using individual variables, but should be storing the values in a list like `names` then use `names[0]` etc. to access individual items.

In your case you can get the number of players and append to a list in each loop iteration. In the end you'll have a list of player names:

```
num_players = int(input('How many people are playing?'))
players = []

for i in range(num_players):
    p = input(f'Who is player {i+1}?')
    players.append(p)

print(players)
```